# Terraform reference to undeclared local value when using defaults function

Tags: terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I want to do the following:

1. Declare 3 fields `private_dns_zone_id`, `private_cluster_enabled`, `public_network_access_enabled` and their default values for all environments *except* one.
2. Use aks.auto.tfvars in the exception environment and "override" the default values.

However, I am getting an error message like:

```
│ Error: Reference to undeclared local value
│ 
│   on aks.tf line 10, in resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "myaks":
│   10:   private_cluster_enabled       = local.private_cluster_enabled
│ 
│ A local value with the name "private_cluster_enabled" has not been declared.
```

Here are what my tf and tfvars files look like:

aks.tf

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "global" {
  name                          = var.aks.name
  ...
  
  # values required to making AKS public / private
  private_dns_zone_id           = local.private_dns_zone_id
  private_cluster_enabled       = local.private_cluster_enabled
  public_network_access_enabled = local.public_network_access_enabled

  ...
}
```

aks.variables.tf

```
variable "aks" {
  description = "Azure Kubernetes Service Values"
  type = object({
    ...
    private_dns_zone_id           = optional(string)
    private_cluster_enabled       = optional(bool)
    public_network_access_enabled = optional(bool)
    ...
  })
}

locals {
  aks = defaults(var.aks, {
    private_dns_zone_id           = "System"
    private_cluster_enabled       = true
    public_network_access_enabled = false
  })
}
```

aks.auto.tfvars (for the "exception" environment)

```
aks = {
  private_dns_zone_id = ""
  private_cluster_enabled = false
  public_network_access_enabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only to fix one thing:

```
private_cluster_enabled = local.aks.private_cluster_enabled
```

and it should work. This is because variables of type map have a key (or keys in your case) and a value (or values in your case). To access any of the values you have to specify the variable name followed by the key name.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/types#maps-objects

Comment: Wow. That was a complete brain fart on my part. Thank you.